# Vim do not set syntax to file any more after crash?

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

My System was crashed yesterday, the problem is that syntax is disable and `set autoindent` is not in use.

Even I remove this file, touch this file again, it remains not right!

Comment: And what would have been right?

Comment: Do you rely on any sort of automatic session save/load plugin?

Comment: @Ben I use [spf13-vim](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim)

Comment: [I think you should reconsider using spf13](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+spf13), then.

Answer (score 0):

**Swap files are not meant to edit directly.**

Swap files are special files that store pieces of Vim's state, and pieces of the unsaved file, in a Vim-specific format. These are *not* backup files.

You may be able to use the swap file to recover any edits-in-progress. To do that, simply edit the file you were editing when your system crashed. Vim will detect the swap file and prompt you to recover the file if it is able to do so.

That is, if you haven't invalidated the swap file format attempting to edit it in a misguided attempt to recover your file from it by hand.

Now, Vim *does* have a separate ability to make real backup files that are copies of your file, whenever it saves. But that doesn't help you from a system crash, that helps you when you mess up your file yourself while you edit, and then save it.

There is also a proposed new feature (in the todo list) for adding a command to recover an entire file from an undo file, if the file itself got deleted somehow, but that's not included in any released Vim yet.

Comment: sorry, I explain myself wrong, it is the crash that make vim do not set syntax to the crashed file(now, edit the file, syntax is disable and do not  set autoindent )